# Emploi de « ce » comme pronom impersonnel

Tags: usage, pronoms, pronoms-impersonnels

J'emploie couramment l'expression « C'est quelle heure ? », en général pour demander l'heure. La plupart des francophones que je connais emploie pourtant l'expression « Il est quelle heure ? » à défaut du plus formel « Quelle heure est-il ? ».

Y a-t-il d'autres emplois courant de ce type ? Par exemple, « ça pleut » est-il envisageable ? Sont-ils tous de registre familier ?

Comment: _la plupart_ + singulier ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grevisse encore.

> Au lieu de *il*, la langue parlée populaire et familière emploie parfois *ça* avec des verbes essentiellement impersonnels exprimant des phénomènes météorologiques, surtout si le phénomène a une intensité particulière.

Plutôt que Proust ou Aragon cités par Grevisse, je vais citer H. Dès

> Car ça pleut ça pleut ça pleut
>   Car ça pleut ça pleut ça pleut
>   Si ça pleut qu'est-c'que j'y peux
>   Car ça pleut ça pleut ça pleut

Grevisse remarque plus loin

> Dans l'indication de l'heure, au lieu du tour ordinaire *Il est ...*, on trouve parfois *c'est*. Dans certains cas, le démonstratif pourrait marquer un rapport avec ce qui précède, mais cette analyse n'est pas toujours possible. Il y a sans doute des influences régionales, notamment chez les auteurs du Midi.

et il cite Barrès, Gide, Proust, Châteaubriant, Giono, P. Benoit, Pagnol, ...

Comment: De toute façon, chez nous dans le Sud, ça pleut pas beaucoup, mais quand ça pleut, ça pleut ! ;)