# How to translate “evidence” from English to French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

I have a very hard time translating the word “evidence” to French, where evidence is used in the context of science, as in Carl Sagan's famous quote:

> Extraordinary claims require extraordinary **evidence**

As a skeptic, I am often in need of such a word or phrase when (for example) explaining around me why it is not rational to believe that homeopathy is an effective treatment because all scientific **evidence** is that it works no better than a placebo.

- **preuve**: not OK. “preuve” is too strong a word in this context. In many cases in science you don't "prove" something, but you collect evidence and when the collected evidence overwhelmingly fits some hypothesis, then it becomes irrational to believe a contradictory one.
- **éléments de preuve**: slightly better. The reference to a proof is still annoying though.
- **présomption**: not OK. Perhaps appropriate in relation to a lawsuit or a trial. Also, “présomption” is derived from “présumer” which relates to an opinion that is held *a priori*, in absence of evidence.
- **faits à l'appui**: perhaps. I don't like it very much, as it is a mouthful.

So did I miss something or French doesn't have good, short, to the point word to express the meaning of **evidence**?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

L'éventail de sens du mot *[preuve](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/preuve)* en français est assez large, et couvre à la fois certains sens du mot anglais *evidence* et certains sens du mot *proof*. Le mot *preuve* est donc correct dans le sens demandé ici, même si je comprends que tu ne veuilles pas l'utiliser à cause de son ambiguïté.

Puisque tu insistes sur l'aspect [réfutable](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9futabilit%C3%A9) de la science, je propose d'utiliser la terminologie [popperienne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper) : ***[corroboration](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corroboration)***. Ce mot n'est pas très courant, et risque d'être compris comme un synonyme de *confirmation* par un public non familier avec l'épistémologie, mais vu le contexe cela ne devrait pas poser de problème.

S'agissant de la citation de [Carl Sagan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan) en particulier, elle a un [historique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan#Personal_life_and_beliefs) en partie francophone. Avant lui, [Marcello Truzzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcello_Truzzi) disait : « An extraordinary claim requires extraordinary proof. » Cette phrase est une traduction en anglais d'une formulation de [Théodore Flournoy](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9odore_Flournoy), qui énonçait dans [*Des Indes à la Planète Mars*](https://archive.org/details/desindeslaplan00flou) (ch. X, p. 344–345) :

> Il convient, pour les mieux mettre en lumière, de les formuler isolément en deux propositions représentant les principes directeurs, les axiomes, de toute investigation du supranormal. L'un, que je nommerai Principe de Hamlet, peut se condenser en ces mots : **Tout est possible**. L'autre, auquel il est juste de laisser le nom de Principe de Laplace, est susceptible de bien des expressions ; je l'énonce ainsi : **Le poids des preuves doit être proportionné à l'étrangeté des faits**. ».

Flournoy se fonde sur une remarque de [Laplace](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Simon_de_Laplace), que l'on trouve dans son [*Essai philosophique sur les probabilités*](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL25265654M/Essai_philosophique_sur_les_probabilit%C3%A9s) ainsi que dans l'introduction de sa [*Théorie analytique des probabilités*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=6MRLAAAAMAAJ&pg=PR62&lpg=PR62&dq=%22examiner+avec+une+attention+d%E2%80%99autant+plus+scrupuleuse%22&source=bl&ots=lkbqOiBwad&sig=uArVlst303xs1Vsr0Ofc6IQz_2E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Kx5ZU_m2HOqu4QSNrYFg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22examiner%20avec%20une%20attention%20d%E2%80%99autant%20plus%20scrupuleuse%22&f=false) (dans une section intitulée « Du Calcul des Probabilités, appliqué à la recherche des phénomènes et de leurs causes »). Laplace lui-même ne s'aventure pas à utiliser de mot comme *preuve*, se limitant à parler de *probabilité* (ce qui est le thème de son œuvre, donc ne nous permet pas de tirer de conclusion quand à son choix de mot).

> Nous sommes si loin de connaître tous les agents de la nature et leurs divers modes d'action, qu'il serait peu philosophique de nier les phénomènes, uniquement parce qu'ils sont inexplicables dans l'état actuel de nos connaissances. Seulement, nous devons les examiner avec une attention d'autant plus scrupuleuse, qu'il paraît plus difficile de les admettre; et c'est ici que le calcul des probabilités devient indispensable, pour déterminer jusqu'à quel point il faut multiplier les observations ou les expériences, afin d'obtenir en faveur des agents qu'elles indiquent une probabilité supérieure aux raisons que l'on peut avoir d'ailleurs, de ne pas les admettre.

Comment: Excellent. J'ai en particulier la référence à Laplace. Evidemment je me situe dans le contexte popperien, mais aussi dans la situation très (trop) fréquente en France où je cherche à détourner mon interlocuteur des sirènes de quelque charlatanisme. Dans ce cas, il est rare que je puisse compter sur une quelconque familiarité avec la méthode scientifique en général ou l'épistémologie.

Comment: En tout cas "corroboration" semble être le plus proche de ce que je cherchais. Il a l'inconvénient d'être peu courant, ce qui peut parfois être un avantage dans une conversation en attirant l'attention de l'interlocuteur (ou au contraire suggérer de la pédanterie :-()

Comment: En effet, "corroboration" me rappelle les cours de Vérification (Audit) dispensés par des professeurs Canadiens (missionaires) de l'UQTR et de HEC Montreal: i.e. consonnance technique marquée.

Comment: Cette expression (« Le poids des preuves doit être proportionné à l'étrangeté des faits ») est connue sous le nom de Principe de Laplace, nom attribué par Théodore Flournoy dans son ''Des Indes à la planète Mars : étude sur un cas de somnambulisme avec glossolalie'' (1899). Flournoy résume ainsi le propos de Laplace, qui se lit :

Comment: Nous sommes si éloignés de connaître tous les agens [sic] de la nature, et leurs divers modes d’action ; qu’il ne serait pas philosophique de nier les phénomènes, uniquement parce qu’ils sont inexplicables dans l’état actuel de nos connaissances. Seulement, nous devons les examiner avec une attention d’autant plus scrupuleuse, qu’il paraît plus difficile de les admettre ; et c’est ici que le calcul des probabilités devient indispensable [...]

Comment: [..] indispensable, pour déterminer jusqu’à quel point il faut multiplier les observations ou les expériences, afin d’obtenir en faveur des agens [sic] qu’elles indiquent, une probabilité supérieure aux raisons que l’on peut avoir d’ailleurs, de ne pas les admettre. - ''Essai philosophique sur les probabilités'', Paris, 1814 (2e éd.)
http://books.google.ca/books?hl=fr&id=rDUJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA50

Comment: @Urhixidur Thanks, I've now found the quote in Flournoy's text, which is clearly the origin of that sentence.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I think the word "**preuve**" is the best word for the above citation. Without getting into an epistemological argument, I don't think your opinions on the "unprovable" aspect of applied sciences should really weigh in (they would certainly meet strong disagreement from a scientist like Carl Sagan).

That being said, if you are so strongly opposed to the word "preuve", the next best word would probably be "**démonstration**", which generally translates "[mathematical/scientific] proof" rather than "evidence", but would fit nicely in the context above:

> Une affirmation extraordinaire appelle à une démonstration extraordinaire.

Comment: I like "démonstration" better than "preuve". But it seems to me you misunderstood my point: the crucial point is that science is falsifiable, not unprovable. Your attempt suggests also the alternative "mise en évidence": "Une affirmation extraordinaire appelle à une miss en évidence extraordinaire" is not so bad.

Comment: @Jean-Denis Muys: I think I fully understand your argument, and as I said, still disagree with the gist of it. But I don't think here is the proper place to have an epistemological debate (and I doubt we would come out any more convinced of each other's position: both having equally valid arguments to back them up). BTW, I'm not sure "mise en évidence" would be an appropriate translation here (despite its tempting etymological similarities with the English).

Answer (score 3):

Pour commencer, lors de la traduction d'une expression comme celle-là, le fait que *preuve* soit un peu plus fort qu'*evidence* ne me semble pas un mal, on fait de toute manière suivre par *extraordinaire*.

> Une affirmation extraordinaire demande des preuves extraordinaires.

Tu peux éventuellement enlever l'*extraordinaire* pour ne pas trop amplifier l'idée initiale.

> Une affirmation extraordinaire demande à être prouvée.

me semble pas mal. Ou si tu tiens à éviter *prouver*,

> Une affirmation extraordinaire demande à être étayée par des faits probants.

Ensuite, *preuve* n'a uniquement un sens absolu.  Sinon on ne parlerait pas de *preuves insuffisantes* ou de *preuves irréfutables*. Il me semble simplement que la division du champ sémantique entre *indice* (qui est à coup sûr trop faible ici) et *preuve* en français se fait ailleurs qu'entre *evidence* et *proof* en anglais.

Comment: +1 pour "faits probants"

Comment: À moi ça m'en semble un (de mal), et les preuves irréfutables me semblent plus le produit de stylisticiens que d'épistémologues, qui ont davantage leur mot à dire sur cette question.

Comment: j'aime assez l'idée de "fait probant", mais je continue à rejeter "prouver" ou "preuve", parce qu'il invite à un faux sens, ou tout au moins à une contradiction de l'interlocuteur fondée sur une mauvaise lecture du mot.

Answer (score 3):

I've ran into that problem in my works.

In French, we generally will use "preuve" in most cases. Although this is not a good answer. Then I think that in some cases "pièce à conviction" would be interesting since it has the sense of something use to find the truth.

---

J'ai été confronté à ce mot dans mes travaux.

En français, on utilisera le terme "preuve" dans la plupart des cas. Bien entendu, je suis conscient que cela ne réponds à la question. Je pense donc que, selon les cas, il est plus intéressant d'utiliser **"pièce à conviction"** en ce sens où celle-ci sert à la recherche de la vérité.

Comment: J'aurais tendance à ne pas utiliser _pièce à conviction_ en dehors d'un contexte juridique.

Comment: @Unfrancophone je n'aime pas trop ça non plus, mais j'ai pas mieux.

Comment: "fait à l'appui" reprend l'idée de "pièce à conviction" sans avoir la connotation juridique

Answer (score 2):

In certain cases, for example in police work, you could use *indice*.

Comment: I like this translation. I wish we used it in science.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu parles du nom, *constatation* me paraît adéquat dans un contexte scientifique.
Pour ce qui est du verbe, *démontrer* ou *attester* devrait faire l'affaire.
Dans ta citation, *justification* s'en rapprocherait le plus.

Answer (score 1):

Les traductions habituelles de la citation *Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence* (voir par exemple l'article Wikipédia sur [Marcello Truzzi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcello_Truzzi#%C2%AB_Affirmations_extraordinaires_%C2%BB)), ainsi que ses sources en anglais et en français utilisent *preuve*, *poids de la preuve* ou *fardeau de la preuve*.

Pour ma part, je suis également perplexe vis-à-vis de ce terme dans un contexte scientifique: une preuve est par définition irréfutable et ce qui est scientifique est par définition réfutable.

Dans la deuxième phrase proposée: *It is not rational to believe that homeopathy is an effective treatment because all scientific* ***evidence*** *is that it works no better than a placebo*, j'utiliserais volontiers le terme "***arguments*** *scientifiques*".

J'ai aussi pensé au verbe **étayer** mais j'ai rarement rencontré le nom associé **étai** au sens figuré.

Incidemment, cela me rappelle la citation de Frédéric Dard: [*L'hypothèse la mieux élaborée ne saurait prévaloir sur la réalité la plus bancale.*](https://qqcitations.com/citation/150078)

Answer (score 1):

Une piste pour ajouter à la réflexion : j'hésite aussi à utiliser ''une preuve'' mais au pluriel, ''des preuves'' sous-entend qu'il en faut plusieurs pour appuyer une démonstration, que chaque preuve individuelle n'est pas LA preuve de quelque chose mais un indice de plus, un élément de preuve.

Comment: Bonne idée. Je viens de l’utiliser dans un forum pour la citation de Carl Sagan. Ca peut le faire.

Answer (score 0):

Un terme fréquemment utilisé en finance est *empirique*. Je ne sais pas si c'est approprié dans ce contexte-ci cependant.

> Des études empiriques démontrent que […]

C'est souvent utilisé dans un contexte pour signifier « ce n'est pas une preuve scientifique / fondamentale, mais c'est statistiquement fort probable que ».

Comment: J'ose pas changer moi-même avec tous ces descriptivistes™ qui traînent par ici, mais *[il](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/emploi-de-ce-comme-pronom-impersonnel)* me semble que la dernière phrase mériterait d'être rectifiée ;-)

Comment: Je ne comprend pas le commentaire :-S Je ne dis pas que je suis d'accord, ou pas, je ne le comprend simplement pas! Mais c'est pas grave, je vous fais confiance! :-P

Comment: Pardon, mon commentaire est vraiment pas très clair. En fait, comme on venait d'en parler récemment, je me disais que « il est […] probable que » semblait un peu plus… hmm… correct… que « c'est probable que ».

Comment: L'empirisme est le fondement de la méthode scientifique, qui collecte des observations (empiriques), à la suite desquelles émet des prédictions, ensuite confirmées ou infirmées par l'expérimentation. Donc *empirique* est dans le même champ sémantique, mais reste distinct

Answer (score 0):

I am arriving a little late to get my answer to be really useful, but anyway I think (I am a French, from France, and I recently arrived in the United States in order to work and study, and I am subsequently having a hard time to do not make too much proof of evidences in English, as a french who knows better 'readen'-English than how communicative English should be..), ...

... -So, I was writing that my "*I-French*" think- that the author should act upon-pedant and use the 'combination' "élément de preuve" while insisting on the last part of the word "élément", but *above all* meanwhile not forgetting to being **conscious** acting pedant ; and I believe that in that singular case, **only**, one could then communicate a widespread -clear- understanding of himself to French people in the room

Answer (score 0):

> Les assertions extraordinaires requièrent des phénomènes extraordinaires.

Mais mon préféré c’est l’idée de Knu, ce qui donnerait dans ce cas :

> Les assertions extraordinaires requièrent des constatations extraordinaires.

Answer (score -6):

Le mot « évidence » existe en français aussi... ce mot ne veut-il pas dire la même chose qu'en anglais?

Comment: _évidence_ means something obvious or _obviousness_ depending on the context, not an _evidence_. You need _evidences_ when something isn't an _évidence_ :)