# Le sujet d'une construction impersonnelle est-il toujours 'il' ?

Tags: sujet, pronoms-impersonnels

La phrase « C'est dommage. » est-elle aussi une construction impersonnelle ?

Une autre question. *Ça* quand il s'agit de quelque chose en particulier, *il* quand il s'agit d'un état ou d'une situation générale. Alors, dans une phrase qui commence avec *ça*, il ne s'agit pas d'une construction impersonnelle parce que *ça* désigne plutôt quelque chose ?

Answer (score 3):

Dans la phrase ***C'est dommage***, le pronom ***ce*** fait référence à un fait connu, on ne peut pas remplacer la phrase par ***Il est dommage*** sans devoir la compléter par une explication donc ce n'est pas une tournure impersonnelle.

Pour répondre à la question du titre, on peut trouver ***ce*** et ***ça*** dans quelques constructions impersonnelles comme ***C'est l'heure !*** et ***Ici quand ça neige, ça neige !***

Voir [Emploi de « ce » comme pronom impersonnel](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/emploi-de-ce-comme-pronom-impersonnel)