# Quelle est la nature de "ça" dans les phrases du registre familier "ça pleut" "ça mange" ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Je n'ai pas trop trouvé d'informations à propos du "ça" sur internet utilisé de cette façon...

"Ça" est souvent considéré comme un replacement familier de "cela" et donc identifié à un pronom démonstratif... Mais que dire des phrases suivantes :

"Ça pleut !"

"Oh, aujourd'hui, ça chante !"

Ou encore, en frontière :

"Un chien, ça mange beaucoup."

Pour la première phrase, j'aurais envie de dire "pronom impersonnel", au même titre que "il" dans "il pleut"
Pour la seconde, si on omet que des personnes réelles chantent, et on qu'on considère que ces chants qu'on entend font finalement partie de la "météo du jour"... je dirais la même chose que la première...
J'ai l'impression que ce "ça" permet de transformer presque tout verbe en un verbe impersonnel.

Quant à la troisième, je dirais pronom indéfini mais clairement, je ne suis pas sur de moi... Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ce type d'utilisation est présenté dans *Le bon usage*:

> **c)** Les démonstratifs neutres *cela*, *ça* s'emploient fréquemment pour
> désigner un être ou une chose qu'on ne veut ou ne peut nommer avec
> précision.
> Il s'agit de quelque chose qui est mal identifié : *Devant moi, quelque chose apparaissait* [...]; *ÇA semblait instable, perfide, engloutissant ; ÇA remuait et ÇA se démenait partout à la fois* (Pierre Loti, *Roman d'un enfant*, IV). — *ÇA avait glissé dans mes jambes, ÇA avait frôlé mes mollets, et c'étaient des vipères* (Antoine de Saint-Exupéry, *Terre des hommes*, p. 86).
> [...]
> Le sujet est vague, non identifié, et le pronom démonstratif est proche de
> *il* impersonnel, avec lequel il peut parfois commuter : *ÇA sent la résine, la menthe, l'écorce brûlée* (MAURIAC, Asmodée, II, 1). — *ÇA bouchonne sur l'autoroute « Il y a des bouchons »*.

Voir aussi: [Emploi de « ce » comme pronom impersonnel](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/emploi-de-ce-comme-pronom-impersonnel)

Comment: J'ai vu des linguiste dire que *ça* ne peut pas être pronom impersonnel, mais franchement, en tant qu'informaticien ayant fait un peu de théorie de langages (informatiques hein...), je ne peut m'empêcher de trouver que ce "ça" peut difficilement se distinguer du "il" impersonnel dans cet usage là...

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50015/1109